How to get Meta Ads Account ID using Cloud APIs or Graph APIs?
Is retrieving the Meta Ads Account ID using Cloud APIs or Graph APIs possible? I have checked the documentation but couldn't find relevant information. If you know anything related to this, please share. How can I get the IDs, and what steps do I need to follow?"
